# Compare Two different size list of lists and create a new list

Tags: python, list, compare

I have the following two list of lists:

```
A=[['NUCPANT     500.00', 'MID500      500.00', '1 '], ['MID230      230.00', 'DOWNTN      230.00', '2 ']]
B=[['NUCPANT     500.00', 151], ['MID230      230.00', 153], ['DOWNTN      230.00', 154], ['MID500      500.00', 152]]
```

Required output:

```
C = [[151, 152, '1'],[153, 154, '2']]
```

What I wanted in the output is:

1. if first element of each sub-list in A ('NUCPANT     500.00') is equal to first element of sub-list in B ('NUCPANT     500.00') then first element of sub-list in C (151) should be the second element of sub-list of B
2. if second element of each sub-list in A ('MID500      500.00') is equal to first element of sub-list in B ('MID500      500.00') then first element of sub-list in C (153) should be the second element of sub-list of B

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't that be `C = [[151, 152 <- Not "153", '1'],[153, 154, '2']]`?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far ?

Comment: @KenY-N My apologies, you got it right. Let me correct in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to get what I wanted

```
sdxBrnInfo = []
for x in sdxReader:
    for y in busNamebusNumber:
        if (x[0] == y[0]):
            for z in busNamebusNumber:
                if (x[1] ==z[0]):
                    sdxBrnInfo.append([y[1], z[1], x[2]])
```